# Converting large integer to 8 byte array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to convert a large number into an 8 byte array in javascript.

Here is an IMEI that I am passing in: 45035997012373300

```
var bytes = new Array(7);
for(var k=0;k<8;k++) {
  bytes[k] = value & (255);
  value = value / 256;
}
```

This ends up giving the byte array: 48,47,7,44,0,0,160,0. Converted back to a long, the value is 45035997012373296, which is 4 less than the correct value.

Any idea why this is and how I can fix it to serialize into the correct bytes?

Comment: Heads up, `value` will be a global variable.

Comment: How are you converting back to a long?  This works just fine, for instance: http://jsfiddle.net/zuqgJ/

Comment: @Elliot - This is code within a function.

Comment: @mellamokb - The byte array gets passed via UDP to a .NET (C#) windows service, which deserializes it using the BitConverter class.

Comment: can you add the conversion back to the long?

Comment: This would do it `BitConverter.ToInt64(new byte[] {48,47,7,44,0,0,160,0}, 0)`.  Returns the value `45035997012373296`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your value and the [largest JavaScript integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t) compared:

```
45035997012373300  // Yours
 9007199254740992  // JavaScript's biggest integer
```

JavaScript cannot represent your original value exactly as an integer; that's why your script breaking it down gives you an inexact representation.

Related:

```
var diff = 45035997012373300 - 45035997012373298;
// 0 (not 2)
```

**Edit**: If you can express your number as a hexadecimal string:

```
function bytesFromHex(str,pad){
  if (str.length%2) str="0"+str;
  var bytes = str.match(/../g).map(function(s){
    return parseInt(s,16);
  });
  if (pad) for (var i=bytes.length;i<pad;++i) bytes.unshift(0);
  return bytes;
}

var imei = "a000002c072f34";
var bytes = bytesFromHex(imei,8);
// [0,160,0,0,44,7,47,52]
```

If you need the bytes ordered from least-to-most significant, throw a `.reverse()` on the result.

Comment: @mellamokb Try [changing the value to `45035997012373301`](http://jsfiddle.net/zuqgJ/1/).

Comment: @Phrogz - so what's the workaround? I can store the IMEI as a string in javascript to make sure I don't lose precision. But I still need a way to convert it to 8 bytes.

Comment: @Phrogz: Yep, looks like that's the problem.

Comment: where does the imei come from? i have implemented an entire bit manipulation library in javascript and i believe i can solve the problem, but i need to understand the source of the input

Comment: See my edit if you can express your string as hex instead of decimal. Otherwise @mellamokb seems to have this under control.

Comment: Aren't you missing the eight bit, i.e., should have `0` at the beginning before `160`?

Comment: @mellamokb _(edits code quickly)_ I have no idea what you're talking about. ;)

Comment: @Phrogz: Too late.. Just missed the 5-minute window :P

Comment: Switched answer to this one. Thanks to both of you for your help, I originally was using melllamokb's code but it ended up not working for certain large values. I changed my code to return the IMEI in hex, and then serialize to bytes using Phrogz's code, and it works great!

Answer (score 3):

Since you are converting from decimal to bytes, dividing by 256 is an operation that is pretty easily simulated by splitting up a number in a string into parts.  There are two mathematical rules that we can take advantage of.

1. The right-most n digits of a decimal number can determine divisibility by 2^n.
2. 10^n will always be divisible by 2^n.

Thus we can take the number and split off the right-most 8 digits to find the remainder (i.e., `& 255`), divide the right part by 256, and then also divide the left part of the number by 256 separately.  The remainder from the left part can be shifted into the right part of the number (the right-most 8 digits) by the formula `n*10^8 \ 256 = (q*256+r)*10^8 \ 256 = q*256*10^8\256 + r*10^8\256 = q*10^8 + r*5^8`, where `\` is integer division and `q` and `r` are quotient and remainder, respectively for `n \ 256`.  This yields the following method to do integer division by 256 for strings of up to 23 digits (15 normal JS precision + 8 extra yielded by this method) in length:

```
function divide256(n)
{
    if (n.length <= 8)
    {
        return (Math.floor(parseInt(n) / 256)).toString();
    }
    else
    {
        var top = n.substring(0, n.length - 8);
        var bottom = n.substring(n.length - 8);
        var topVal = Math.floor(parseInt(top) / 256);
        var bottomVal = Math.floor(parseInt(bottom) / 256);
        var rem = (100000000 / 256) * (parseInt(top) % 256);
        bottomVal += rem;
        topVal += Math.floor(bottomVal / 100000000); // shift back possible carry
        bottomVal %= 100000000;
        if (topVal == 0) return bottomVal.toString();
        else return topVal.toString() + bottomVal.toString();
    }
}
```

Technically this could be implemented to divide an integer of any arbitrary size by 256, simply by recursively breaking the number into 8-digit parts and handling the division of each part separately using the same method.

Here is a working implementation that calculates the correct byte array for your example number (`45035997012373300`): http://jsfiddle.net/kkX2U/.

```
[52, 47, 7, 44, 0, 0, 160, 0]
```

Comment: Your array is in reverse order (showing bytes from least-significant to most).

Comment: It's in the same order posted by the OP, and is also the correct order for `BitConverter.ToInt64` in `C#` as I've tested it.

Comment: But it differs from my answer, so it must be wrong. :) I didn't notice the "reversed" order of bytes by the OP; good point.

Comment: Ya as I commented on OP you can test with this in LINQPad: `BitConverter.ToInt64(new byte[] {52,47,7,44,0,0,160,0}, 0)`.  I assume conversion takes them in the same order sent, and not FIFO over the UDP stream.  The networking/bit side of things I don't have a good grasp of.

Answer (score 0):

store the imei as a hex string (if you can), then parse the string in that manner, this way you can keep the precision when you build the array. I will be back with a PoC when i get home on my regular computer, if this question has not been answered.

something like:

```
function parseHexString(str){
   for (var i=0, j=0; i<str.length; i+=2, j++){
      array[j] = parseInt("0x"+str.substr(i, 2));
   }
}
```

or close to that whatever...

Comment: Note that you can simply use `parseInt('af',16) // 175`